# Painel para ocultar elementos página usuário PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html5

Boa noite, estou fazendo um sistema de gestão para a empresa e agora apareceu uma exigência não prevista que preciso ajustar. Dentro da página administrativa de cada cliente existem botões que na verdade são imagens que ao clicar os direcionam para uma parte específica do site, mas meu chefe quer que a visualização desses botões seja determinada por ele individualmente. Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um painel master que oculte ou exiba esses elementos de acordo com a vontade do administrador. Estou usando PHP com banco de dados Mysql

Comment: Como você está usando banco, você poderia criar uma tabela ou coluna de controle, relacionada diretamente com os clientes, onde você pode guardar valores de "mostrar" e "esconder" ou 1 e 0, por exemplo. Na hora de você montar a página, utilizaria um "if", para verificar se determinada pessoa possui o critério de mostrar os botões, se sim, insere os botões, se não, não coloca.

Comment: Tenta postar algum código de como estão os botões e a estrutura, ajuda a resolver o problema.